# Facebook permissions crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, permissions

Once the user is already logged in with read permissions (which is completely working fine) I need to ask him for publish permissions:

```
NSArray *publishPermissions = @[@"publish_actions", @"user_photos"];
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithPublishPermissions:publishPermissions fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"FB error: %@ || result: %@", error, result);
    }];
}
```

If in the given code snippet I just ask for `publish_actions` everything is working fine and I get the log. If I just ask for `user_photos` or for both the app is crashing with general `NSException`.

**Why `user_photos` is causing such an issue and what to do to make it working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on Facebook-Swift implementation, it went out that only public permissions starting with `public` or `managed` are handled, all others will cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch everything from this code :

```
{
NSString *getFbid;
 NSString *getFbFirstName,*getFBlastName, *getFbemail,*getfbBirthday,*getfbGender,*getFBpHone,*getFBlocation,*getFBcountry;

}



-(void)loginButtonClicked
{



FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login
 logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile",  @"user_friends", @"email"]
 fromViewController:self
 handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         DLog(@"Process error======%@",error.description);
         indicators.hidden=YES;
         [indicators stopAnimating];
     } else if (result.isCancelled) {
         DLog(@"Cancelled");
         indicators.hidden=YES;
         [indicators stopAnimating];
     } else {

         if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {



             [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , gender ,friendlists"}]
              startWithCompletionHandler:^(
                                           FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                  if (!error)
                  {

                      //  NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

                      // [self fetchingFacebookFriends];

                      [defFacebookData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"fbEmail"];

                      [defFacebookData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"fbID"];


                      //PASS ID
                      getFbid  = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"getFbid========>%@",getFbid);

                      //PASS FIRST NAME
                      getFbFirstName=[result objectForKey:@"first_name"];

    NSLog(@"first======>%@",getFbFirstName);

                      //PASS LAST NAME
                      getFBlastName=[result objectForKey:@"last_name"];
    NSLog(@"first======>%@",getFBlastName);

                      //PASS EMAIL
                      getFbemail=[result objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSLog(@"first======>%@",getFbemail);

                      //PASS PHONE
                      getfbGender=[result objectForKey:@"gender"];
    NSLog(@"first======>%@",getfbGender);


                      [defFacebookData setObject:[result objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"fbName"];

                      // Image
                      FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                                    initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/picture?type=large&redirect=false"]
                                                    parameters:nil
                                                    HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                      [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                            id fbImageResult,
                                                            NSError *error) {

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[fbImageResult objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"url"]];

    NSLog(@"strURL=====>%@",strURL);

[defFacebookData setObject:strURL forKey:@"fbImage"];

                          [defFacebookData synchronize];


                          NSDictionary *fbdict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:getFbid,@"id",getFbFirstName,@"first_name",getFBlastName,@"last_name",getFbemail,@"email",getfbGender,@"gender",strURL,@"fbImage", nil];

                          NSLog(@"done=========>%@",fbdict);


                      }];
                  }
                  else{

                      DLog(@"error is %@", error.description);
                  }
              }];
         }
     }
 }];
}
```

Comment: This neither does publish anything (all are GETs) nor touches the issue of the image. Did you read the question..?

Answer (score 0):

```
Swift 3 IOS 10.2

First:

@IBAction func goLoginFacebook(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if (error == nil){
                let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                    {
                        self.getFBUserData()
//                        fbLoginManager.logOut()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dict)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueFacebookNavigator", sender: self)

                }
            })
        }
    }

Second: Where require publish add

 @IBAction func goPublishFacebook(_ sender: UIButton) {


        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil
        {

            print("User is logged in")

            if !(FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions")) {

                print("Request publish_actions permissions")
                requestPublishPermissions()
            }
            else{
                sendVideoFacebook()
            }



        }else
        {
            print("User is not logged in")

        }
    }

    func requestPublishPermissions()
    {
        let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        login.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"], from: self) { (result, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error!)
            } else if (result?.isCancelled)! {
                print("Canceled")
            } else if (result?.grantedPermissions.contains("publish_actions"))! {
                print("permissions granted")
                self.sendVideoFacebook()
            }
        }
    }


    private func sendVideoFacebook()
    {
        var pathURL: NSURL
        var videoData: NSData
        // self.pathVideo path file in disc
        pathURL = NSURL(string: self.pathVideo)!
        videoData = try! NSData.init(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: self.pathVideo) as URL)

        let strDesc = txtMessage.text!
        let videoObject: [String : AnyObject] = ["title": "application LetsMovies" as AnyObject, "description": strDesc as AnyObject, pathURL.absoluteString!: videoData]
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: videoObject, httpMethod: "POST")


        self.view!.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            self.view!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                print(result!)
                print(self.dict)

            }
        })


    }
```

Comment: Your answer does not explain the crash. The crash was happening because iOS implementation does not read `user_photos` permission request. That's a bug in Facebook API (it should at least return an error, not crash).

Answer (score -1):

Replace This. this is working fine in my app

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
        [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];

        [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday"]
         fromViewController:self
         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

             if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email,name,birthday,first_name,last_name,gender"}]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                  {
                      if (!error)
                      {
}
                      else
                      {
                          NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
                      }
                  }];
             }
         }];
```

Comment: Ew. I don't want to READ user profile. I want to WRITE to it. That answer does not help at all. And it has nothing in common with `user_photos` at all! Did you read the question..?